# Displaying multiple menus in a loop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to material-ui and React and I have a requirement to create multiple menus dynamically in a loop. Please find the code snippet as:

```
state = {
    anchorEl: null,
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

    render() {
        const { anchorEl } = this.state;
        let items = _.map(results, (item, index) => {
        return (
              <ListItem
               key={item.ID}
               divider
              > 
              <ListItemSecondaryAction>
               <IconButton
                   aria-label="More"
                   aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'long-menu' : null}
                   aria-haspopup="true"
                   onClick={this.handleClick}
                  >
                  <MoreVertIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                  <Menu
                   id="long-menu"
                   anchorEl={anchorEl}
                   open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                   onClose={this.handleClose}
                   PaperProps={{
                     style: {
                        maxHeight: 200,
                        width: 200,
                      },
                   }}
                  >
                <MenuItem>
                    <IconButton onClick={() => this.props.delete(item.ID)} >
                     Delete entry<DeleteIcon />
                     </IconButton>
                </MenuItem>
              </Menu>
             <ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItem>
          )
        })
       return (
              <Fragment>
                <List>
                 {items}
                 </List>
              </Fragment>
             )
      }
```

Now, with the above code, the menus work fine and the UI is good. But whenever I try to delete an entry by clicking on Delete icon inside the menu, always the last entry is deleted i.e. item.ID passes the value of the last element and the last entry is deleted.
Is there a way I can create unique menuitems for each entry and manage the state in such a way which makes sure that the correct item is deleted and not the last one always.
Note: 'results' is any list loaded dynamically and 'delete' function implements the functionality to delete the corresponding entry

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are successfully passing the unique ID of the item to the delete function it should be working correctly. There might be an issue with the delete function. Please update your question with contents of that function.

Comment: the delete function works correctly if I place the onclick event on a button instead of creating this menu item. So, it seems to be the issue with this UI approach

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest use another child component for render your list item. In your current example you only one `anchorEl`, which means wherever you click, always one menu open and take action of that, which is last one. If you have child component for menu item, each component will have there own state and work for that item only.

#### Example

```
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    let items = _.map(results, (item, index) => {
      return (
        <MenuItemComponent key={item.ID} item={item} onClick={this.handleClick} onDelete={(item) => this.props.delete(item.ID)} />
      )
    })

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <List>
          {items}
        </List>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

class MenuItemComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;
    const { anchorEl } = this.state;

    return (
      <ListItem
        divider
      >
        <ListItemSecondaryAction>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="More"
            aria-owns={anchorEl ? 'long-menu' : null}
            aria-haspopup="true"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
          >
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Menu
            id="long-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={this.handleClose.bind(this)}
            PaperProps={{
              style: {
                maxHeight: 200,
                width: 200,
              },
            }}
          >
            <MenuItem>
              <IconButton onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(item)} >
                Delete entry<DeleteIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </ListItem>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/nn555l48xm

Comment: How you are accessing the handleClick method in the parent component which is defined in the child component?

Answer (score 0):

```
    import * as React from "react";
import {
Menu,
MenuItem,
IconButton
} from "@material-ui/core";

import MoreVertIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreVert";


export default function Demo() {
const [openElem, setOpenElem] = React.useState(null);
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

const handleClick = (elem) => (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    setOpenElem(elem);
};

const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    setOpenElem(null);
};

let arr = [0, 1, 2];
let body = arr.map((elem) => {
    return (
    <div key={elem}>
        <IconButton
        aria-label="more"
        aria-controls={"long-menu" + elem}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick(elem)}
        >
        <MoreVertIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Menu
        id={"long-menu" + elem}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={openElem === elem}
        onClose={handleClose}
        >
        <MenuItem
            onClick={(e) => {
            handleClose();
            }}
        >
            {elem}
        </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </div>
    );
});

return <div>{body}</div>;
}
```