# React, Material Ui: Unable to map a value on a hidden menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mapping, menuitem

Hello guys I hope u are having a good time

Im mapping an array, and everything works cool but all the hidden [menus](https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#simple-menu) (opens after click) shows the id of the last item of the array, I can not find if its because is hidden while the mapping but im unable to get the id of each element in that section of the component

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const handleClickPoints = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
      };
    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };
return (
{array.map((value)=>(  
    <Typography> {value.name} </Typography> 

     {/*
   some other values correctly mapped
*/}

{/*not mapping value.id here: */}
<MoreHorizIcon aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClickPoints} />
        <Menu
            id="simple-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            keepMounted
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}
        >         
   <Link href={`/edit/${value.id}`}><MenuItem onClick={handleClose}><Typography>Edit details</Typography></MenuItem></Link>
        </Menu>
  ))}
)
```

Any idea of how to map values in a hidden menu? or what else could it be?

Comment: You have a single state for all menus. When you click you open *all* menus with the same `anchorEl`, the last one just happens to be on top. You will be able to see this in the DevTools when inspecting the DOM. You need each menu to have its own `anchorEl` state

Comment: okay cool! I just created another component for the menu, and pass the value.id as a prop. similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962846/displaying-multiple-menus-in-a-loop) but using hooks. all working fine now. thanks